# how to post multiple images to firebase and get their download url?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, ionic3

I am using ionic 3 and firebase. I am trying to upload multiple images at once using for each loop. After uploading them i need to get the download url to store them in the database. since the getting "download url" part is asynchronous, I have to insert the data into the databse after the .then() part of image uploads....How can I go about this?  This is what i got so far after the form is submitted:

```
post_news(form: NgForm){

    this.title = form.value.title;
    this.content = form.value.content;
    this.category = form.value.category;


    console.log(this.capturedimage1);


    if(this.capturedimage1 !== ''){


        this.images_to_upload.push(this.capturedimage1);


    }



    if(this.capturedimage2 !== ''){

        this.images_to_upload.push(this.capturedimage2);
    }

    if(this.capturedimage3 !== ''){

        this.images_to_upload.push(this.capturedimage3);
    }


    if(this.capturedimage4 !== ''){

        this.images_to_upload.push(this.capturedimage4);
    }



    images_url_from_db = [];

    this.images_to_upload.forEach(function(item){


        let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

        const filename = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

        const imageRef = storageRef.child(`images/${filename}.jpg`);





     imageRef.putString(item, firebase.storage.StringFormat.DATA_URL).then(data=>{

     images_url_from_db.push(downloadURL);



     });


    })

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be useful for someone out there...After playing around a long time I figured out a way to do this.....first I insert the non-image data into the DB like(title,content,category). then I get the inserted data's key . I then use the key to upload the images one by one, which will insert the image url as image1, image2,image3, and so on...

```
post_news(form: NgForm){

    this.title = form.value.title;
    this.content = form.value.content;
    this.category = form.value.category;


    this.news = this.afDb.list('/news');
    this.news.push({title: this.title,content: this.content, category: this.category}).then(data=>{

        var item_key = data.key;

        console.log(data.key);

        if(this.capturedimage1 !== ''){

            let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

            const filename = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

            const imageRef = storageRef.child(`images/${filename}.jpg`);


            imageRef.putString(this.capturedimage1, firebase.storage.StringFormat.DATA_URL).then(data=>{

            this.news = this.afDb.list('/news');
            this.news.update(item_key, {image1: data.downloadURL}); 


            });
        }


        if(this.capturedimage2 !== ''){

            let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

            const filename = 'img'+Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

            const imageRef = storageRef.child(`images/${filename}.jpg`);


            imageRef.putString(this.capturedimage2, firebase.storage.StringFormat.DATA_URL).then(data=>{

            this.news = this.afDb.list('/news');
            this.news.update(item_key, {image2: data.downloadURL}); 


            });
        }



        }).then(data=>{



            form.reset();
            this.capturedimage1 = '';
            this.capturedimage2 = '';
            this.navCtrl.parent.select(0);

        });





}
```